# PrintDocument scale to fit page

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

Let’s say I have a PrintDocument with unknown number of pages. How could I scale it to fit everything on one page?

Edit:
I am trying to achieve something like “fit to page” when printing.

Comment: divide by 4? or use magic putty.....

Comment: what if number of pages is unknown? what would be the best approach for getting page count? Once I know number of pages how do I merge them to one?

Comment: Just run the page rendering code more than once.  First with a Graphics object you get from PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many pages your document has, you will never ever be able to find out the right scaling. You have to put some effort in finding out the amount of pages and then you will be able to set the scaling.

**Edit**:

One hint for measuring the pages: Print out the document "blind" (will say not to the printer, print it to a graphics you will get with PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics() like Hans Passant stated in his comment). Then you will have the amount of pages. You can then set the scaling and print the document the second time, but this time direct to the desired printer.

Comment: I think hes asking how to get the number of pages in addition to printing them on one page.

Comment: Ah, here it is: "what if number of pages is unknown? what would be the best approach for getting page count? Once I know number of pages how do I merge them to one?" posted 27 minutes prior to your answer.

Comment: @Blankasaurus: You're right, I've edited my answer.

Comment: The only solution I have seen so far was printing to file and counting pages. Is there a better way?  How can you set scale, I couldn’t find anything for PrintDocument ?

Comment: Following you suggestion I started looking at PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics() I came across post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116424/how-to-preprocess-printdocument-to-calculate-the-total-number-of-pages-before-pr) explaining my page counting problem. I am still not sure how to scale it to one page. Any hints?

Comment: Ok so I can use Graphics.ScaleTransform to scale it. Any suggestions how to get all pages as one graphic?